# magento 2 api /V1/products/attributes/{attributeCode}/options add attribute options

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am trying this code to add an option to an attribute:

```
$sampleOptionData = array(
    "label"     => "2200",
    "value"     => "2200",
    "sortOrder" => 100,
    "isDefault" => false,
    "storeLabels" => array (
        array( "storeId" => 1, "label" => "2200" )
    ),
);

$arrayData = json_encode(array('option' => $sampleOptionData));


$ruta = 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.php/rest/V1/products/attributes/metros/options';

$ch = curl_init( $ruta );

$curlOptions = array(
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => "POST",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $arrayData,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array( "Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . $token)
);

curl_setopt_array( $ch, $curlOptions );

$response = curl_exec( $ch );

// Comprobar el código de estado HTTP
if (!curl_errno($ch)) {
  switch ($http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)) {
    case 200:  # OK
        print_r($response);
        break;
    default:
      echo 'Código HTTP inesperado: ', $http_code, "\n";
      print_r($response);
  }
}

// Cerrar el manejador
curl_close($ch);
```

but when run i get this error:

> HTTP code: 400
>   {"message":"Cannot save attribute %1","parameters":["metros"]}

metros is an attribute product a its {attribute_code} is "metros".

Important if I run similar code in python works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry the solution is in the field "value". It does not exist value = "2200".

If I comment this line the code works fine.

Regards